# How to use ui-bootstrap-paginagion in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I create a directive to show data in table. I want to add pagination to this. I use it like:

```
app.directive('myTable', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            /** default variable */
            var fields  = scope[attrs.fields];
            var rows    = scope[attrs.rows];
            var currentElement = element; // if it remove element.replaceWith run just one time
            var pagination = { 
              current_page:1,
              from:1,
              last_page:1,
              next_page_url:null,
              per_page:10,
              prev_page_url:null,
              to:2,
              total:2
            };


            /** watch data change */
            scope.$watch(attrs.rows,function(newData) {
                rows = newData;
                fields  = scope[attrs.fields];
                if(rows){
                    pagination = newData.metadata;
                }
                scope.render(rows,fields);
            },true);

            /** Render HTML function */
            scope.render = function(rows,fields) {
                /** begin of table */
                var html = '<div class="res-table"><table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fixed ellipsis-table" ><thead><tr>';

                /** Create table header */
                angular.forEach(fields, function (item, index) {
                    html += '<th>' + item.field + '</th>';
                });
                html +='</tr></thead><tbody>';


                /** Create column and cell */
                angular.forEach(rows, function (row, index) {
                    html +='<tr>';

                    angular.forEach(fields, function (item, index) {
                        // if hasn't dot (.)
                        if(item.field.indexOf('.') === -1 ) {
                            html += '<td>' + row[item.field] + '</td>';
                        } else {
                            // split field by dot (.)
                            var splitFieldName = item.field.split('.');
                            // check if is array
                            if(Object.prototype.toString.call(row[splitFieldName[0]]) === '[object Array]'){
                                // iteration for field is array
                                var tmp = [];
                                angular.forEach(row[splitFieldName[0]],function (value, key) {
                                    tmp.push(value[splitFieldName[1]]) ;
                                });
                                html += '<td>' + tmp + '</td>';

                                // if it's null
                            }else if(row[splitFieldName[0]]===null) {
                                html += '<td>-</td>';
                            }else{
                                html += '<td>' + row[splitFieldName[0]][splitFieldName[1]] + '</td>';
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    html +='</tr>'
                });
                html +='</tbody></table></div>';

                /** pagination */
                console.log(pagination);
                html +='<div class="text-center"><uib-pagination total-items="'+ pagination.total +'" ng-model="' + pagination.current_page +'" max-size="5" class="pagination" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" ng-change="pageChanged(perPage)" items-per-page="' + pagination.per_page +'"></uib-pagination></div>';


                /** Replace in html */
                var replacementElement = angular.element(html);
                currentElement.replaceWith(replacementElement);
                currentElement = replacementElement;
            };

        }
    }
});
```

[CodePen script](https://codepen.io/essvision/pen/BzxjyG)

I don't know about $compile to compile angularjs directive in other directives. How to use it?

Thanks